# Get Value from Json HTTP response

Tags: c#, json, vb.net, linq

Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Public NotInheritable Class MainPage

```
Inherits Page

Public result As String = ""
Public Sub Btn_Test_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Btn_Test.Click
    getRequest("http://192.168.1.242/control?callback=cname&cmd=get_state_sensor&number=1")
    Dim s As String = result

    TBox1.Text = result

End Sub


Public Async Sub getRequest(uri As String)
    Dim httpClient As New System.Net.Http.HttpClient
    Dim response As System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage = Await httpClient.GetAsync(uri)
    result = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems you have forgotten to ask a question. Please take a moment to read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Parse or deserialize the json.  Cant say much more (beyond please read [ask] and take the [tour]) without knowing what you really want or what the json looks like